# How do I delete in Django? (mysql transactions)

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, transactions

If you are familiar with Django, you know that they have a Authentication system with `User model`.  Of course, I have many other tables that have a Foreign Key to this `User` model.

If I want to delete this user, how do I architect a script (or through mysql itself) to delete every table that is related to this user?

My only worry is that I can do this manually...but if I add a table , but I forget to add that table to my DELETE operation...then I have a row that links to a deleted, non-existing User.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand it, django does an "on delete cascade" by default:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a script for this. When you delete a record, Django will automatically delete all dependent records (thus taking care of its own database integrity).

This is simple to test. In the admin, go to delete a User. On the confirmation page, you'll see a list of all dependent records in the system. You can use this any time as a quick test to see what's dependent on what (as long as you don't actually click Confirm).

If you perform deletions from your view code with `.delete()`, all dependent objects will be deleted automatically with no option for confirmation.

From the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects):

> When Django deletes an object, it
>   emulates the behavior of the SQL
>   constraint ON DELETE CASCADE -- in
>   other words, any objects which had
>   foreign keys pointing at the object to
>   be deleted will be deleted along with
>   it.